# Cluster centroids for hierarchical clustering

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I performed a hierarchical clustering using `hclust()` on some text data using `stringdist`. I got a dissimilarity matrix between the strings and named it `distancemodels`.

Now I am trying to find the centers for each clusters using the code below:

```
dists = as.data.frame(distancemodels)
dists$ID = as.integer(rownames(dists))

# this adds the clusters information
dists = merge(dists,clusters[,c(1,4)])

#k = number of clusters
meds = as.vector(1:k)

#This for loop is throwing the following error: Error in colMeans(dists[dists$cluster == i, as.character(dists$ID[dists$cluster ==  :'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
for(i in 1:k){meds[i] = as.integer(names(colMeans(dists[dists$cluster ==      i,as.character(dists$ID[dists$cluster == i])])[unname(which(colMeans(dists[dists$cluster == i,as.character(dists$ID[dists$cluster == i])])==min(colMeans(dists[dists$cluster == i,as.character(dists$ID[dists$cluster == i])]))))]))[1]}

medians = as.data.frame(unlist(t(t(meds))))
medians$cluster = rownames(medians)
```

As I couldn't find any help from the Internet on how to find cluster centroids for `hclust`, this is something I wrote. Please let me know where I am going wrong. I am very new to R.

Comment: What do you mean by "centers"? You can use cutree to break the tree apart at heights or number of subtrees, but it's not clearly meaningful to talk about clusters for hierarchical clustering without explaining a bit more.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. I have a rows of short sentences and need to cluster them according to similarity. But I also need to justify why we are putting them in a single cluster. I have distances between any two sentences, but there is no common point of reference. So I am trying to calculate the central point(sentence) by finding the point whose mean distance from all the other points in the same cluster is the minimum.

Comment: take a look at something like silhouetteWidth -- also, you might want to post on cross-validated as this is starting to get pretty statistical.